# can not filter UNSeen email IMAP php( CPANEl)

Tags: php, search, imap, cpanel

I wanna see all unread email on IMAP with php on php 5.6 and cpanel
I use imap_search with UNSEEN tag like this

```
$some   = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN', SE_UID);
```

but it shows me all massage. when I filter search by subject it works well but I can not filter it by seen, unseen, ANSWERED and ... as define here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: And what is the IMAP server?  Have you verified that it's not a problem with the server?

Comment: I use Cpanel Imap server and every thing works fine on mail server.I can mark mail as read and unread on the webmail but I want do it on php

Comment: I don't think "cpanel" is the brand of the IMAP server.